# Sprite-kit: How to position sprites on a circular path

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I am experimenting with Sprite-kit, to build circular path where the main character can follow and collect coins. I have successfully positioned my character and made him follow my circular path.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- red ball is the main character [done]
- white polygons are the coins

[image: schema]

```swift
// Adding the big circle
let runway = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "runway")
runway.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))
addChild(runway)
// Adding the player
player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
player.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX(frame) , (CGRectGetMidY(frame) + runway.size.width/2) )
// Calculating the initial position of the player and creating a circular path around it
let dx = player.position.x - frame.width / 2
let dy = player.position.y - frame.height / 2

let radian = atan2(dy, dx)
let playerPath = UIBezierPath(
    arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame)),
    radius: (runway.frame.size.width / 2) - 20,
    startAngle: radian,
    endAngle: radian + CGFloat(M_PI * 4.0),
    clockwise: true)

let follow = SKAction.followPath(playerPath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
```

My problem now, is how to position my coins on that same path ??
Is there a way to generate their positions using the same path or should I create a specific path for each coin and extract the path `currentPoint` each time ??

Is there a simpler way to solving my problem ??

Thanks

Comment: The link to the image is broken... You may add how and where you create the path to get a better answer. But in general, you need to know where is the center of your circular path and what is its radius. Based on that, you can easily calculate points on circumference (which is the actual path you are talking about).

Comment: I've updated my initial post with some code, hoping it could help others understand my problem. I can see the image and it's not broken for me. Weird ?!

Comment: Yeah weird. I can't open it neither from device or computer. Paste link in the comments(if you like)...Updated code is enough though.

Comment: [Dropbox: Link to image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsaodtsbqkcz3a5/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202016-03-30%2023.34.01.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said, you need to know where is the center of the path (in your case that is `CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY)` which is "center" of the screen) and you have to know the radius (you have it already calculated when you was creating the path) and you need an angle that the ray from center `(frame.midX,frame.midY)` to the point on the circumference `(coinX,coinY)` makes with positive x axis:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = SKSpriteNode(color: .purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        // Adding the big circle
        let runway = SKSpriteNode(color: .orangeColor(), size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))
        runway.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))
        addChild(runway)
        // Adding the player

        player.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX(frame) , (CGRectGetMidY(frame) + runway.size.width/2) )
        addChild(player)
        // Calculating the initial position of the player and creating a circular path around it
        let dx = player.position.x - frame.width / 2
        let dy = player.position.y - frame.height / 2

        let radius = (runway.frame.size.width / 2) - 20.0

        let radian = atan2(dy, dx)
        let playerPath = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame)),
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: radian,
            endAngle: radian + CGFloat(M_PI * 4.0),
            clockwise: true)

        let follow = SKAction.followPath(playerPath.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
        player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))

        let numberOfCoins = 8
        for i in 0...numberOfCoins {

            let coin = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))

            let angle = 2 * M_PI / Double(numberOfCoins) * Double(i)

            let coinX = radius * cos(CGFloat(angle))
            let coinY = radius * sin(CGFloat(angle))

             coin.position = CGPoint(x:coinX + frame.midX, y:coinY + frame.midY)
            addChild(coin)
        }
    }
}
```

Just a sidenote : In Sprite-Kit the angle of 0 radians specifies the positive x axis. And the positive angle is in the counterclockwise direction. The source - [Building Your Scene](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode).

Comment: The link to "Building Your Scene" looks broken now. Thanks!

Comment: @nbloqs Ah okay. Thanks for pointing that and for the upvote! I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that Whirlwind posted is valid, but needs to be migrated to work with Xcode 11.

The following is an updated version of that answer, along with an animation showing it in action.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    // Adding the big circle
    let runway = SKSpriteNode(color: .orange, size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))
    runway.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    addChild(runway)
    // Adding the player

    player.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY + runway.size.width / 2)
    addChild(player)
    // Calculating the initial position of the player and creating a circular path around it
    let dx = player.position.x - frame.width / 2
    let dy = player.position.y - frame.height / 2

    let radius = (runway.frame.size.width / 2) - 20.0

    let radian = atan2(dy, dx)
    let playerPath = UIBezierPath(
        arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY),
        radius: radius,
        startAngle: radian,
        endAngle: radian + CGFloat(.pi * 4.0),
        clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.follow(playerPath.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
    player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(follow))

    let numberOfCoins = 8
    for i in 0...numberOfCoins {

        let coin = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))

        let angle = 2 * .pi / Double(numberOfCoins) * Double(i)

        let coinX = radius * cos(CGFloat(angle))
        let coinY = radius * sin(CGFloat(angle))

         coin.position = CGPoint(x:coinX + frame.midX, y:coinY + frame.midY)
        addChild(coin)
    }
}
```

How it appears in action:

[image]